Intuition and proof behind finding the day of the week by the date
I am reading david m. Burton's elementary number theory and came across this theorem in the chapter of arithmetic function

Theorem 6.12$\quad$ the date consisting of the day d, month m, year Y=100c+y where c≥16 and $0≤y<100$ is $$w=(d+\lfloor(2.6)m-0.2\rfloor -2c+y+\lfloor\frac{c}{4}\rfloor +\lfloor\frac{y}{4}\rfloor)\mod7 $$

Now this was proven in 3 pages which he progresses the formula under the assumption that the year starts in March from
$$D_y=D_{1600}+L\mod7$$ which gives the first day of the year for every year ($D_y$) (1st of March) using the first day in the year 1600,the year you want to find (Y) and the amount of leap years from the starting year to the current year (L)
He then finds L to be
$$L=24c+\lfloor\frac{y}{4}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{c}{4}\rfloor-388$$
Then goes on to loost the first day of every month and express some other thing I didn't quite Get and come out with the theorem's formula.
What? What did he even do in the theorem??? Why is this long formula the expression of every day in the year since 1600?

$\lfloor(2.6)m-0.2\rfloor$ is the only surprising term; it just works. The rest is clear. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence#Analysis
